# Yubikey 5 HMAC-SHA1 Challenge/Response with APDU commands

Tags: smartcard, apdu, hmacsha1, yubico

I’m developping following this [reference guide](https://docs.yubico.com/yesdk/users-manual/application-otp/otp-commands.html#challengeresponse), I try a simple HMAC-SHA1 Challenge/Response with APDU commands.

I tested the APDU commands with a Yubikey 4 : it works without problems

```
Using reader: "Yubico Yubikey 4 CCID 0"
Sending APDU: "00a4040008a000000527200101"
APDU response: "040301030300010f00009000"
Sending APDU: "000130000953616d706c65202332"
APDU response: "0922d3405faa3d194f82a45830737d5cc6c75d249000"
```

The same commands fail with my Yubikey 5 nano :

```
Using reader: "Yubico YubiKey OTP+CCID 0"
Sending APDU: "00a4040008a000000527200101"
APDU response: "0504030303009000"
Sending APDU: "000130000953616d706c65202332"
APDU response: "6985"
```

The 69 85 response means "Conditions of use not satisfied."

Both slots are configured for HMAC-SHA1 challenge.
I suspect there is some bug in the yubikey 5 firmware : is there something I’m missing ?

Comment: Have you looked up the meaning of the commands and responses? I mean, just sending bytes specified in hexadecimals without understanding what they do or what is returned seems lazy at best. That's like saying that you don't understand what was said in Morse code, it only did beep beeperdy beep.

Comment: I'm not throwing random bytes : look at the link to the reference guide in my post, it describes the commands and responses. The final 69 85 response with the yubikey 5 should be the HMAC-SHA1 response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an answer from the Yubico customer support ; this is a 5.4.3 firmware limitation.

> In the YubiKey 5.4.3 firmware, when communicating over a physical connection, the OTP function can only accept APDUs which configure the OTP behaviors. If you would like to access the Challenge-Response over a physical connection, please use the HID interface - this is detailed in the Desktop SDK documentation: https://docs.yubico.com/yesdk/users-manual/application-otp/how-to-calculate-a-challenge-response-code.html. Please be aware that the current limitation is only for the physical connection. When communicating with the YubiKey over NFC, the Challenge-Response function works as expected, and the APDUs will behave in the same manner as observed in the 4.X firmware.